# Opting out of hiding spoiler markdown content.

Tags: feature-request, spoilers

I know that you can easily

> Mouse over spoiler markdown to reveal spoiler tag information, but

I would like to suggest an opt-out setting that will automatically show the spoilers for you. This would make them easier to read at once instead of moving the mouse across the screen. Just a suggestion.

I've moved it to [Site-Wide: Opting out of hiding the spoiler text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91682/opting-out-of-hiding-the-spoiler-text) so share your opinion.

Comment: I'll +1, but I'm skeptical that there are many people out there who don't care about being spoiled on *anything*.

Comment: Its not that we don't care, as much as we're partially curious. We all peak... anyway.

Comment: Maybe like a click-on and display an orange box saying "You have disabled hidding spoilers, click again to hide spoilers by default."

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91682/opting-out-of-hiding-the-spoiler-text

Comment: General announcement: [Posting on a child meta is absolutely fine! The Stack Exchange team monitors all of the child metas.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on/89232#89232). Don't make Rebecca Chernoff sad!

Comment: @gilles What happens in cases like this where there are duplicates on child and parent meta?  Does this get closed as a dupe of the parent?  It seems wasteful to repeat answers in both places.

Comment: @Tony: Considering we're one of the biggest users of spoilers on SE at the moment, I think we need to have this question on our meta anyway. @Justin: given that you posted both questions, you'll be notified of answers on both sites, so you'll have the burden of reporting interesting contributions.

Comment: Thanks @gilles, I could use the user script, but I don't want it to harm future functionality.

Comment: I care. I hate spoiling a movie for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spoiler tag is just a bit of CSS.  I believe all modern browsers allow use of a user style sheet.  So all you need to do is add a rule that overrides the CSS in your user style sheet, and you're done.

(I don't think user style sheets can be site-specific, so this would change *any site* that uses the "spoiler" CSS class.  If that does have an impact, then IMO a better feature request would be to have SE change the class to something like "stackexchange-spoiler").

For example, in Safari, go to *Preferences*, then *Advanced*, then select the stylesheet.

Your stylesheet only needs to contain something like this:

```
.spoiler { color: #444 !important; }
```

444 is the colour that you get when hovering (at least on this site) - you could make it something else if you wanted spoilers to stand out in some way (e.g. so you avoid referencing them in answers!).

Answer (score 2):

This is far too much of a niche feature to be implemented in the Stack Exchange software. But this is easily fixed on the browser side.

See [the similar question on the main Stack Exchange meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91682/site-wide-opting-out-of-hiding-the-spoiler-text) for a [user script by Michael Mrozek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91682/site-wide-opting-out-of-hiding-the-spoiler-text/91690#91690).

There's a [Stack Exchange site for user scripts](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts). I don't see any script about spoilers right now. If you find or write one, please announce it here.

Comment: PS, I wrote that question.

Answer (score 1):

I've created the [StackApps entry](https://stackapps.com/q/2404/301) for the UserScript and a Safari Extension.